# How to put Labels in of a list of number in a chart?

Tags: string-manipulation, plotting, labeling

I can´t put the labels 0,....,31 in this simple chart

on the usual place, or better just over the Top of each bar

How should I do?

```
f1[x_] := 12 x^5 - 975 x^4 + 28000 x^3 - 345000 x^2 + 1800000 x
a = Table[i, {i, 0, 31}]
fa = f1[a]

amix = Table[{i, f1[i]}, {i, 0, 31}]

atext = Table[ToString[i], {i, 0, 31}]
atext
BarChart[amix, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
 ChartLabels -> {atext, Top}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need:

```
f1[x_] := 12 x^5 - 975 x^4 + 28000 x^3 - 345000 x^2 + 1800000 x
BarChart[f1 /@ #, ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, 16] & /@ #, Above]] &@Range@31
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ok and anly for personal likes.... Do you know how to put labels OVER and just OUTSIDE the bar?

Comment: In this way... I can´t replace BarChart with ListPlot.

How do you would do with ListPlot?

Comment: @MikaIke For the legends, use **Above** instead of **Top**.

Comment: @MikaIke `ListPlot[]` and `BarChart[]` are very different beasts. You can't usually switch'em (perhaps only if you're using very basic non-specific options)

Comment: ok, I see that can´t switch them. Do you know use a larger siza in the labels?

Comment: @MikaIke See edit

Comment: OK, fantastic responses!. The Last... How Can I include the value of 0 (that is 0) in the bars?. I question this for other examples where the bar is not cero.

Comment: I want to put the 1,...31 on the Top (not above) of the bar, so I must switch Top/Above. But the question is: How can I ADD the bar value Above? (plus the label in the Top of de bar 1,....31)